# PHP - Make Directory Code Not Working

Tags: php, html, directory, dir

I am having a problem with some PHP code and I cannot seem to understand why it isn't working.

So, to cut a long story short I'm creating a social network site and users are allowed to upload their own profile picture. To disallow other people to be able to view everyones pictures I am making it so that went a user uploads a profile picture it creates a new randomly generated directory. When I click Upload, it isn't creating the Directory. (No pictures should go into the directory at this moment in time, only the directory should be made, but it isn't). Thanks for you help.

PHP Code:

```
if (isset($_FILES['profilepic'])) {    if
(((@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") ||
(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/png") ||
(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/gif"))&&(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["size"]
< 1048576)) //1 Megabyte   {    $chars =
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";   
$rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);   
mkdir("./userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name");

}
else
{

}
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<p style="font-size: 20px;">Upload a Profile Picture</p><br />
<form action="" method-"POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<img src="./img/default_pic.png" width="70" height="70">
<input type="file" name="profilepic" /><br />
<i>Your Profile Picture must <b>not</b> violate any of the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>!</i><br />
<input type="submit" name="uploadpic" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

Comment: is your variable meant to be commented out? and are the > actually in your code?

Comment: For one thing, you've got a stray `if` and your bracing's way off.

Comment: Does the profile_pics folder exist in your ./userdata directory already?

Comment: @LiamSorsby: My variable isn't commented out in the 'real' code but for some reason when I copy and pasted it here it went all compact and funny.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's not a stray, but like i said, when I copy and pasted it over here it compact itself and looks quite messy.

Comment: @Lee Yes it already exists.

Comment: @BuddyLog Please make sure if this isn't a permission issue firstly as apache may not have permission to create the directory

Comment: It could be a permissions issue, yet from what's been posted below, that method doesn't always work, as I've seen in many cases. Using `chmod` with the variable before it gets created is a way to do this, although very tricky. You could try the answer below, but again... not entirely sure it will work.

Comment: Can you try `mkdir("./userdata/profile_pics/" .$rand_dir_name);`

Comment: @Fred-ii- tried that and again nothing.

Comment: Enable php error reporting. You should get an error message if something is failing such as mkdir()

Comment: @Lee I added this code to the PHP: ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1); and I got a few undefined variable errors. Sorted that out. Got no errors when uploading though, yet still nothing.

Comment: I tested the `mkdir` part on my server and it checked out. Now, the way you have your code laid out here, this `//1 Megabyte   {    $chars =` will not work, since `{    $chars =` are literally commented out. That's "IF" that's the way your code is. Other than that, I don't know. Depends also from where you're executing this from. I tested the `mkdir` code from my root, with a subfolder called `test` and it created a randomly-named folder under `test`

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's not commented out for me, but for the sake of testing, I'll remove that 1mb comment and try again.... Tried again and still nothing.

Comment: Do both `userdata` & `profile_pics` folders exist and are they already set to be writeable? If "one" or those is not writeable, then it won't let you create another folder inside it. And are you running this from `root/code.php` or other folder?

Comment: @Fred-ii- just changed the permissions to 0777 and still nothing. At least I know that the permissions were set wrong, but that can't be the only problem.

Comment: I don't know what else to tell you at this point, except maybe remove the `./` from the beginning. (baffled)

Answer (score 0):

If your parenthesis and other code is correct than there could be a problem for the directory of the permission if you are on the Linux server or/and nested directories have not been created

try this

```
mkdir ("./userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name", 0777 , true);
```

second parameter is octal value which give it widest permission and third parameter allow mkdir to also make nested directories like userdata and profile_pics.

Comment: changed it and still nothing. I'm using Coffee Cup Direct FTP if that helps in any way. I tried this using Filezilla and it also didn't work.

Comment: Are you looking for directories on right place. because you are using relative path with ./ 
Try it with absolute path . You can find absolute path with phpinfo() function

Comment: as far as I am aware yes. I have tried it without adding ./ and it didn't change anything.

Comment: after removing ./ did you add absolute path ? You can find absolute path up to your current file by echo phpinfo() and than search for _SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]

Comment: I echoed this: $fullpath = dirname(__FILE__); and got this: /srv/disk13/1592237/www/buddylog.atspace.co.uk/

Comment: try to give path like this and see if it works 

"/srv/disk13/1592237/www/buddylog.atspace.co.uk/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name"

Comment: If it still not works than you can see the Apache or IIS logs to see any possible errors there.